# How to stop same timeout function to override each other CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am using 2 functions that are different in functionality but have same timeout timings. The reason I have timeout is I want to wait for DOM/virtual to load/refresh then I can put on the classes but the function that runs in last overrides. How can I make it so the function doesn't conflict

```
function one(){
 setTimeout(()=>{
        if(message.innerText.includes("D"){
            message.classList.add("green");
      }else if(message.innerText.includes("U")){
          message.children[0].classList.add("red");
      }
}, 5000)
}
```

and other function

```
 setTimeout(()=>{
     const item = captions.replace(/\D/g, "");
       if(item <= 20){
         item.classList.add("amber");
         }else if(itemCaptionsCount >= 20){
         item.classList.add("green");
         }
   })
 },5000) 
}
```

and I call them like the following but when `one()` is run it is fine but when two() is run it overrides the classes which has red from function `one`

```
one()
two()
```

How can I make sure both don't conflict?

For the sake of this question I have made the code very short as it as loop

Comment: you can do it in a single function itself and based on the priority, you can arrange it. Also, instead of timeout, why can't you use the onDomReady ?

Comment: seems odd you would use a timeout and not something else to know when the DOM updates.

Comment: @epascarello I am not really familiar with other things so timeout is only option I see

Comment: @Thinker good idea but it will be non DRY code as I have functions `one` and `two` so making a combo of both will be redundant? also cannot use onDomReady as it will check again based on counter that update the UI and if data changes it will need to change